# Taking IF clauses from MySQL to SQL Server 2005

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I make this MySQL query into SQL Server equivalents?

```
SELECT User.id, User.first, User.last,
IF (User.first = q1 OR User.first = q2, 1, 0) +
IF (User.last = q1 OR User.last = q2, 1, 0) as points
FROM users as User
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to `IF` in SQL Server is the [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28SQL.90%29.aspx). (Or [`IIF` in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).) I also removed the aliases which seem largely pointless in this case.

```
SELECT id, first, last, 
  CASE WHEN first IN (q1,q2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN last IN (q1,q2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS points
FROM dbo.users
ORDER BY points DESC;
```